# jpgraph scatter plot legend

Tags: jpgraph

This is my first post here but I have looked up solutions to my questions here hundreds of times. Thanks to all the helpfull people here!!!

Now to my question:
I haven't used jpgraph for long. so far I've only done pie-plots. In the pie plot I could make legends describing what each slice strands for.

Now I have tried to do the same with a scatter plot. i want a legend describing what each dot stands for.

I have the following data to work with:

```
if ($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($kostenTbl)) {
    do {

            $cost[] = $kostenContainer;
            $price[] = $einnahmen;
            $data_names[] = $kundenName;

    } while ($myrow=mysql_fetch_array($kostenTbl));
}


...

$graph = new Graph(400,250);
$sp1 = new ScatterPlot($price,$cost);

...
```

Now with the pie-plot I could just add...

```
$p1->SetLegends($data_names);
```

... and I got my legend.

Is there any way to do this in a scatter plot?